# MeteorJS: Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Cannot read property 'previousSibling' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

On Meteor 0.7.1.2, a Session variable is used to reactively change the result of a query. When I manually set the Session variable in the browser console:

```
> Session.set('game', 'Tron')

Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Cannot read property 'previousSibling' of null
```

Next I tried the following, which produced no errors

```
> Session.set('game', 'Tron')
undefined
```

Next I tried the following, which game another error (full tracestack below)

```
> Session.set('game', 'anotherGame')
Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

What is causing these errors?

**clientView.js**

```
Template.scores.score = function() {
    return Score.find({game: Session.get('game')})
}
```

**Error**

```
    Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Cannot read property 'previousSibling' of null
        at findPosition (http://localhost:3000/packages/liverange.js?710fe06b230e4e9dea26fab955d6a2badb8467cc:210:12)
        at new LiveRange (http://localhost:3000/packages/liverange.js?710fe06b230e4e9dea26fab955d6a2badb8467cc:159:18)
        at Object.Spark.finalize (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:726:17)
        at http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:697:13
        at LiveRange.operate (http://localhost:3000/packages/liverange.js?710fe06b230e4e9dea26fab955d6a2badb8467cc:490:9)
        at http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:693:11
        at withEventGuard (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:162:16)
        at Object.Spark.renderToRange (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:692:3)
        at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:925:13)
        at Object.Meteor._noYieldsAllowed (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?2b578107b8239ff9bc64200e6af2a24001461b30:530:10)
```

and

```
Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at LiveRange._removeEntries (http://localhost:3000/packages/liverange.js?710fe06b230e4e9dea26fab955d6a2badb8467cc:384:31)
    at LiveRange.operate (http://localhost:3000/packages/liverange.js?710fe06b230e4e9dea26fab955d6a2badb8467cc:479:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:693:11
    at withEventGuard (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:162:16)
    at Object.Spark.renderToRange (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:692:3)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?742c715b73fac26c16ad433118b87045bc5658ff:925:13)
    at Object.Meteor._noYieldsAllowed (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?2b578107b8239ff9bc64200e6af2a24001461b30:530:10)
    at null._func (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?e2b721ea91f036193799d30ccdf652423602aa5c:324:14)
    at _.extend._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?e2b721ea91f036193799d30ccdf652423602aa5c:185:12)
    at _.extend._recompute (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?e2b721ea91f036193799d30ccdf652423602aa5c:198:14)
```

---

Did a check for duplicate `id`s, there appears to be none

```
$('[id]').each(function (i) {
    var ids = $('[id="' + this.id + '"]');
    if (ids.length > 1) {
        console.log(this);
    }
    return;
}).slice(0,0);
```

Comment: The exception seems to be caused while updating the template. Can you post the template code as well?

Comment: also see this page, if it can help you http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/TypeError_-_Cannot_read_property_nodeName_of_null